# Auto refresh new website

Tags: html, css

A website is normally stored in the browser cache. When a website gets a redesign or a complete new design sometimes the "old" website is still stored in the browser. 
When you have a lot of returning customers in a webshop most people don't know that hitting F5 will refresh the page/cache.

How do designers/programmers handle this?

Comment: This is a pretty broad topic..

Answer (score 1):

A typical technique is to add some string like "?version=1.2.3" to the end of the JS and CSS file URLs. That way only a certain version of the files is in the cache, when the version number is changed, the browser knows to ask for a new file.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some tips from google

https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/best-practices/caching?csw=1

What I've always done is externalize as much as possible, and change the names of the external files after redesigns.

Comment: Amazon suggests using random URL parameters that change each version, ie `MyImage.jpg?87346`

Answer (score 0):

try using this in your head tag to force browser to not cache:

```
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" />
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="Tue, 01 Jan 1985 1:00:00 GMT" />
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
```

or via htaccess:

```
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
   ExpiresActive On
   <filesMatch ".(gif|png|jpg|jpeg|ico|pdf|js|htm|html|txt)$">
     Header set Cache-Control "max-age=172800"
   </filesMatch>
</ifModule>
```

http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/speed-up-sites-with-htaccess-caching.html

**UPDATE:**
you can play with the **max-age**..

**0** = never cache

**7200** = 2 hours

**172800** = 2 days

.. and so on and so on

Comment: Disabling all caching is definitely overkill.

Comment: not if its for a specific amount of time like a week or 2 days.. then you can set the max age to 172800 (2days) or 7200 (2 hours) etc.. you can adjust the max-age for your needs